# Get parent in multidimensional hash

Tags: ruby, extends

Checkout this multidimensional hash:

```
hash = { 
       A: { 
            name: 'A', children: {} 
       },
       B: { 
            name: 'B', children: {
                B1: {
                    name: 'B1', children: {
                        B1i: {
                           name: 'B1i', children: {}
                        },
                        B1ii: {
                           name: 'B1ii', children: {}
                        },
                        B1iii: {
                           name: 'B1iii', children: {}
                        },
                        B1iv: {
                           name: 'B1iv', children: {}
                        }
                    }, 
                },
            }, 
       },
       C: {
            name: 'C', children: {
                C1: {
                   name: 'C1', children: {}
                },
                C2: {
                   name: 'C2', children: {}
                }
            }, 
        },                
    } 

def is_a_child_of(parent, child)
   child.parent[:name] == parent ? true : false
end

hash.each do |key, f1|
    puts "F1 generation member: #{f1[:name]}"

    f1[:children].each do |key, f2|

        is_a_child_of('B2', f2)            

        puts "F2 generation member: #{f2[:name]}"

        f2[:children].each do |key, f3|
            puts "F3 generation member: #{f3[:name]}"
        end
    end
end #=>
#
# F1 generation member: A
# F1 generation member: B
# F2 generation member: B1
# F3 generation member: B1i
# F3 generation member: B1ii
# F3 generation member: B1iii
# F3 generation member: B1iv
# F1 generation member: C
# F2 generation member: C1
# F2 generation member: C2
#
```

What is the most **efficient** way to find out each "individual's" parent? Here's a truthy method I wish to use:

```
def is_a_child_of(parent, child)
   child.parent[:name] == parent ? true : false
end
```

However, `child.parent` is complete pseudo code. How could I implenet this parent method?

Or, would it be more `efficient` to simply log the parent in each loop? More pseudo code:

```
hash.each_with_parent do |parent, key, value|
end
```

How could I implement this `each_with_parent` loop?

Would one option to simply save the parent in each hash?

e.g.

```
    B: { 
        name: 'B', children: {
            B1: {
                name: 'B1', parent: 'B', children: {}
            }
        } 
    }
```

Comment: How about `parent.values.any? { |v| v == child }`?

Comment: @UriAgassi I bet it’s the least efficient way to go with.

Comment: @mudasobwa - Ok, so `parent.values.any? { |v| v.equal? child }`

Comment: Though it sounds a bit weird, I would go with altering `hash` with `:parent => ...` tuplas before using. Or, if the hash is being updated hardly during run, monkeypatch the element insertion, providing respective `:parent => ...` addition.

Comment: For your structure to be consistent, the root hash should also have :name and :children keys.

Comment: Seriously, why does someone want to close this?

Comment: @nicooga Thanks, good point. Of course this is just an example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to implement some kind of tree structure where the children nodes keep track of its parent.

This is a simple implementation of a tree that keeps track of children parents:

```
class Tree < Hash
  def initialize(hash = {})
    replace build_tree(hash)
  end

  private

  def build_tree(hash, parent: :root)
    hash.inject({}) do |h,(k,v)|
      h[k] = {
        parent: parent,
        value:  v.kind_of?(Hash) ? build_tree(v, parent: k) : v
      }; h
    end
  end
end

require 'yaml'
puts Tree.new({
  A: {
    A1: 'asdf',
    A2: 'qwer'
  },
  B: {
    B1: {
      B1i: 'uiop',
      B1ii: 'zxcv'
    }
  }
}).to_yaml

--- !ruby/hash:Tree
:A:
  :parent: :root
  :value:
    :A1:
      :parent: :A
      :value: asdf
    :A2:
      :parent: :A
      :value: qwer
:B:
  :parent: :root
  :value:
    :B1:
      :parent: :B
      :value:
        :B1i:
          :parent: :B1
          :value: uiop
        :B1ii:
          :parent: :B1
          :value: zxcv
```

---

**TL;DR**: This [gem](https://github.com/evolve75/RubyTree) looks pretty solid for your use case.

Answer (score 3):

Each hash doesn't know anything about the context it exists in. One approach is to search the whole structure for the child, remember where you found it, and then use that to find the parent. The other is, as you say, to store the parent in each record. Which is best for you depends on how many records you have, how much extra space you want to use recording explicit parents against how much time you want to spend walking over the data structure looking for parents.

You might want to look at some graph libraries for how to store this kind of data structure.